# Read-Through cache with SnappyData

Tags: caching, snappydata

Can we have read-through cache behavior? Meaning application will issue sql query to SnappyData, then SnappyData will check if the data is in the cache (in SnappyData). If it is, it will return the data. If it is not, SnappyData will bring it in to the cache from the data store. The backend data store can be anything sql-compatible data store. This way, application just need to talk to SnappyData, and application does not need to talk to the underlying data storage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, Snappydata ootb cannot be used as a "read through cache", today. That said, we are contemplating supporting a model where the in-memory tables can be configured to manage "hot" data and query could be delegated to backend in some cases.

What class of queries do you wish to run on SnappyData ? perhaps, there is a way to solve.

Answer (score 0):

SnappyData does not have this feature as of today.But we can build our own application where data will flow from some sql compatible data store to snappydata on demand.